RDS Postgres auto recovery breaks Debezium connectors
The Problem
We're running RDS Postgres (16.3) and using a Strimzi to host Debezium connectors for several Postgres tables in K8S.
The problem I'm having is if the database experiences high load, RDS will perform a DB recovery automatically, which takes about 4 minutes.  When the DB recovery completes, the replication slots for my connectors are left inactive, but Debezium thinks everything is okay.  Manually updating the following command will cycle the connector pod and everything fixes itself.
kubectl annotate strimzipodset listing-connector-connect strimzi.io/manual-rolling-update="true"

Auto-recovery is an unfortunate behavior and we'll do our best to mitigate it happening at all, but it's built-in to RDS, and I'd like to find a way to configure the Debezium connectors to recover on their own if this happens.
More Details
As near as I can tell, what's happening is when RDS gets overwhelmed, we see logs that look like this just prior to the db entering recovery mode:
2024-10-01 18:28:13 UTC:10.144.2.119(49204):listing_kafka_connect@listing:[2549]:STATEMENT:  START_REPLICATION SLOT "addorupdatejob" LOGICAL 213/FCD7ED80 ("proto_version" '1', "publication_names" 'dbz_publication', "messages" 'true')
2024-10-01 18:28:13 UTC:10.144.2.119(49194):listing_kafka_connect@listing:[2548] terminating walsender process due to replication timeout

Which seems like the replication slot timed out and RDS killed it.  No big deal, except when the DB comes back, it doesn't fix itself (always).
There seems to be some sort of race condition.  Of the 4 replication slots we have sometimes, 1, 2, or 3 of them will recover successfully when the database returns.
Current configuration
Here's the current configuration of my connector:
Spec:                                                                                                                                                            
  Auto Restart:                                                                                                                                                  
    Enabled:  true                                                                                                                                               
  Class:      io.debezium.connector.postgresql.PostgresConnector                                                                                                 
  Config:                                                                                                                                                        
    database.dbname:                                         ${env:DB_NAME}                                                                                      
    database.hostname:                                       ${env:DB_HOST}                                                                                      
    database.password:                                       ${env:CDC_PASSWORD}                                                                                 
    database.port:                                           ${env:DB_PORT}                                                                                      
    database.user:                                           ${env:CDC_USERNAME}                                                                                 
    decimal.handling.mode:                                   double                                                                                              
    errors.max.retries:                                      0                                                                                                   
    heartbeat.action.query:                                  update public.debezium_heartbeat set heartbeat_timestamp = now() where heartbeat = 'addorupdate-job'
    heartbeat.interval.ms:                                   300                                                                                                 
    plugin.name:                                             pgoutput                                                                                            
    poll.interval.ms:                                        50                                                                                                  
    Predicates:                                              IsHeartbeat                                                                                         
    predicates.IsHeartbeat.pattern:                          addorupdatejob.public.debezium_heartbeat                                                            
    predicates.IsHeartbeat.type:                             org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.predicates.TopicNameMatches                                     
    publication.name:                                        dbz_publication                                                                                     
    slot.drop.on.stop:                                       false                                                                                               
    slot.max.retries:                                        1                                                                                                   
    slot.name:                                               addorupdatejob                                                                                      
    slot.retry.delay.ms:                                     30000                                                                                               
    table.include.list:                                      listing.add_or_update_job_status,public.debezium_heartbeat                                          
    topic.creation.default.partitions:                       6                                                                                                   
    topic.creation.default.replication.factor:               3                                                                                                   
    topic.prefix:                                            addorupdatejob                                                                                      
    Transforms:                                              filter,dropPrefix                                                                                   
    transforms.dropPrefix.regex:                             addorupdatejob.listing.add_or_update_job_status                                                     
    transforms.dropPrefix.replacement:                       omnichannel.listing.sys.add-or-update-job-status.v1                                                 
    transforms.dropPrefix.type:                              org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.RegexRouter                                                     
    transforms.filter.predicate:                             IsHeartbeat                                                                                         
    transforms.filter.type:                                  org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.Filter                                                          
    value.converter:                                         io.debezium.converters.BinaryDataConverter                                                          
    value.converter.delegate.converter.type:                 org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter                                                         
    value.converter.delegate.converter.type.schemas.enable:  false                                                                                               

Originally the max retries were at 10 to ensure it does not run out of retries prior to the DB coming back up, that didn't work at all so I attempted to bring them down in hopes that a more formal "crash" or "disconnect" would result in recovery.
I also attempted to set errors.max.retries to 0 for the same reason.
I feel like this is a pretty common use case and I would expect a product like Debezium for Postgres to be mature enough to gracefully recover from something like this.  I'm sure I'm just configuring something incorrectly.

"Auto-recovery is a normal behavior for RDS": I'm not here to defend Amazon, but that cannot be. You need to give the database enough memory so that it is not killed by the OOM killer.

Sure, and we plan on adjusting for this behavior to mitigate it.  However, if something abnormal happens and RDS recovers itself, I'd like my connectors to be able to gracefully resume as well once the database is back.

Anyway, that is not a software development question...
